# Can JUMflot work on mobile?

Tags: jquery, flot

So I've been looking around in the source code for JUMflot and flot.mouse and it's my understanding that the reason dragging won't work on an iPad either because of the hover functions or the mouse functions. I'm not quite sure what direction I should be looking at for this. If you could tell me what would be causing the problem I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Flot itself does work on mobile. With respect to dragging, I think you will need to add some code to convert touch events into the drag events expected by Flot.

If you have an example somewhere I'd be keen to have a good.